# xfce4-session "cannot connect display" error

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, xfce

I'm trying to run xubuntu-desktop on WSL as per the tutorial given by many sites. But I can't seem to connect to the display of VcXsrv and it always shows:

```
xfce4-session: Cannot open display: .
Type 'xfce4-session --help' for usage.
```

If I run startxfce4, it says:

```
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display muhammadsalmanafzal:0.0
xrdb: Connection refused
xrdb: Can't open display 'muhammadsalmanafzal:0.0'
xfce4-session: Cannot open display: .
Type 'xfce4-session --help' for usage.
```

Although, the VcXsrv window of Xlaunch is closed.
Can anybody help me look for the error? What am I doing wrong?
Also, when I first installed xubuntu-desktop, at the very end it said:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 blueman
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And then I read somewhere to remove it, so I did and reinstalled xubuntu-desktop and no error was given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running WSL 1 then then, you need to add following line to .bashrc in home:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

and run bash again.
However, if you are running WSL 2 then you need get the IPv4 of you WSL network (since by converting to WSL 2, it becomes a network) by checking the ipconfig in Powershell and then export the relative to .bashrc

**[EDIT]**

I think after the windows update to 20H2, the above solution stopped working. So, as per the official recommendation of Ubuntu from [their site](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL#Running_Graphical_Applications), you can add the following lines in your ~/.bashrc and restart it.

```
 export DISPLAY=:0 # in WSL 1
 export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0 # in WSL 2
 export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

Answer (score 2):

a better solution is run:

```sh
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0
```

wsl2 changed when restarted and can't be fixed currently.

https://qiita.com/baibai25/items/5841b0592727893d960f

Comment: Use the above solution. export DISPLAY=:0.0 is not sufficient in my Win 10 home 20H2.

Comment: run, and suppose while executing this: sudo xfce4-session > ~/.xsession

Answer (score 0):

The following two approaches worked for me. I use WSL2.

**Approach -1:**

The title bar of VcXsrv says something like `VcXsrv Server Display MACHINENAME:0.0`.

Start xfce4 with this command: `xfce4-session --display=MACHINENAME:0.0`

Replace `MACHINENAME` with the name of your PC.

Reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1800#issuecomment-455791220

**Approach-2:**

Add the following line to `.bashrc` file.

```
export DISPLAY=MACHINENAME:0.0
```

Again `MACHINENAME` should be the name of your PC

Save the file and restart WSL2.

Now you can just use the command `xfce4-session`.